# Want to display the validation error message above the webform

Tags: 8, webforms

I have a webform created in Drupal 8 using the webform module I have to submit the data to 2 different 3rd party API.

The scenario is I have to submit the data to the 1st API if there is no error response found then submit the data to 2nd API so now I have created a submit handler and attached the handler to the webform. Now the issue is when I got an error response message while submitting the data to 1st API and showing the  message using `drupal_set_message()` function everything is working fine but the form validation js not loading at this point.

**The used code is like the below:**

```
drupal_set_message(t($msg), 'error');
$form_state->setRebuild(true);
```

can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

For form validation error messages you do not use the [drupal_set_message()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/8.6.x) which by the way, it's deprecated.

> Deprecated in Drupal 8.5.0 and will be removed before Drupal 9.0.0.
>   Use [\Drupal\Core\Messenger\MessengerInterface::addMessage](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Messenger%21MessengerInterface.php/function/MessengerInterface%3A%3AaddMessage/8.6.x)() instead.

Back to my point, in forms you don't use the Drupal messager, instead you use the [FormState::setErrorByName](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetErrorByName/8.2.x)

```
$form_state->setErrorByName('field_name', t('Error Message'));
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The messenger is not used to show form validation errors. The other two answers are suggesting complicated code that is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

**you can put the validation messages above the webform by -**

---

1.put the generic element above the form

```
messages:
  '#type': status_messages
```

2.make sure the webform's status messages purge all messages using the below hook in a CUSTOM_MODULE

```
function CUSTOM_MODULE_webform_element_alter(array &$element, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, array $context) {
  if (isset($element['#type']) && $element['#type'] === 'status_messages') {
    $element['#pre_render'][] = 'CUSTOM_MODULE_webform_element_status_messages_pre_render';
  }
}

/**
 * Pre render callback to display status messages element.
 */
function CUSTOM_MODULE_webform_element_status_messages_pre_render($element) {
  // Replace the status messages placeholder with the rendered messages.
  // Calling drupal_get_messages(NULL, TRUE) will purge all messages, which 
  // prevent the messages block from being displayed.
  // @see \Drupal\Core\Render\Element\StatusMessages
  // @see drupal_get_messages()
  $element = [
    '#theme' => 'status_messages',
    '#message_list' => drupal_get_messages(NULL, TRUE),
    '#status_headings' => [
      'status' => t('Status message'),
      'error' => t('Error message'),
      'warning' => t('Warning message'),
    ],
  ];
  return $element;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 8/9 version. Updated version of Wasim Khan solution.

1.Put the generic element above the form. https://SITEURL/en/admin/structure/webform/manage/WEBFORM_ID/source

```
`messages:
  '#type': status_messages`
```

2.Make sure the webform's status messages purge all messages using the below hook in a CUSTOM_MODULE

```
function CUSTOM_MODULE_webform_element_alter(array &$element, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, array $context) {
  if (isset($element['#type']) && $element['#type'] === 'status_messages') {
    $element['#pre_render'][] = 'CUSTOM_MODULE_webform_element_status_messages_pre_render';
  }
}

/**
 * Pre render callback to display status messages element.
 */
function CUSTOM_MODULE_webform_element_status_messages_pre_render($element) {
  // Replace the status messages placeholder with the rendered messages.

  $messages = \Drupal::messenger()->all();

  $element = [
    '#theme' => 'status_messages',
    '#message_list' => $messages,
    '#status_headings' => [
      'status' => t('Status message'),
      'error' => t('Error message'),
      'warning' => t('Warning message'),
    ],
  ];
  return $element;
}
```

3.Also check your twig template, if you have it.